# Filtering nodes and edges neo4j on shortest path

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

Is there a way to run the shortest path algorithm in Neo4J whilst filtering on the edges or nodes with a > operator.
Say filtering on nodes with a higher of something timestamp?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, you can use query predicates for this (http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/query-predicates.html).

Here is an example using the built-in example movie graph. The query finds shortest paths from one `Movie` to another and filters paths which go through Kevin Bacon.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((m1:Movie)-[*]-(m2:Movie))
WHERE m1.title = 'The Birdcage' AND m2.title = 'Sleepless in Seattle'
AND ANY(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.name = 'Kevin Bacon')
RETURN p
```